# Память JVM: как оптимизировать многопоточное приложение?

Tags: java, многопоточность, memory

Господа,
насколько я понимаю модель памяти `JVM` выглядит так: если поток вызывает некий метод класса, то все локальные переменные которые там используются будут созданы не в `HeapMemory`, а в `StackMemory`. Этот `StackMemory` тоже очищается GC и тоже входит как слагаемое в полную доступную `JVM` память (ее можно получить как Runtime.maxMemory()), и, следовательно, чем больше потоков - тем больше занято памяти, даже при том что `HeapMemory` остается без изменений. Т.о. можно записать:
`Runtime.freeMemory() = Runtime.maxMemory() - Thread1Stack - Thread2Stack - ... -` `HeapSpace`.
Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я не прав.

К чему я это спрашиваю: в моем приложении есть специальный поток-наблюдатель, который все время логгирует значение `Runtime.freeMemory()` и иногда оно опускается до сотен байт (однажды вообще было `Runtime.freeMemory() = 8` ). Это приводит к тому, что процесс замедляется и Томкат не отвечает на `HTTP` запросы. Возникает вопрос: может ли при таком низком значении памяти запускаться `GC`?

Я предполагаю, что должна быть связь оптимального количества потоков не только с количеством процессоров, но и с размером памяти. Как мне определить эту связь?

У меня Томкату доступно `Runtime.maxMemory() = 64МБ`, при этом обычно мое приложение запускает 3-4 потока, максимум до 10-12. Мне казалось, что такая нагрузка подходит для процессора т.к. все эти мои потоки очень много спят. Однако судя по тому как мало памяти остается - думать надо не только о процессоре, но и о памяти.

Итак, как понять какое количество потоков оптимально для многопоточного приложения?
Какие кроме `Runtime.freeMemory()` методы отслеживания состояния памяти вы используете? (я не могу запустить профайлер на удаленном хостинге).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы не правы. Объекты всегда создаются в куче. В стеке живут примитивные типы (byte, char, short, int, long, boolean). В стеке хранятся ссылки на объекты в куче.

Все ваши последующие рассуждения, как следствие, не верны. Если у вас всё встревает или даже падает по OOM, то у вас утечка.

В общем, количетсво потоков и память связаны только когда потоков очень много (тысячи). Кроме того, каждому потоку можно указать конкретный размер стека, если вы знаете, какова максимальная требуемая глубина и нет рекурсии. Так что количетсво потоков выбирается таким образом, чтобы оно по возможности не было пропорционально количеству данных приложения и количеству пользователей.

Что же до трёх потоков, то вы забываете о самом томкате, который запускает... очень немало потоков (в зависимости от конфигурации).

Comment: Спасибо! Я основывался на том, что например вот такой класс выдает OutOfMemoryError уже при 50 потоках, а при 2х не выдает:
public class MemoryExample {
 static void doit() {
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
   list.add("STRING");
  }
 }
 void runExample() {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
   Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
     while (true) {
      doit();      
     }
    }
   };
   t.start();
  }
 }
} 
Видимо суть в том что при некотором числе потоков GC не успевает удалять локальные переменные из HeapSpace.

Comment: А могли бы вы пояснить/развить/дать ссылки по этой фразе:
"Кроме того, каждому потоку можно указать конкретный размер стека, если вы знаете, какова максимальная требуемая глубина и нет рекурсии." - вы же сказали что в стеке только примитивы и ссылки, почему в таком случае размер стека важен?

Comment: Потому что примитивы занимают место. А количество потоков влияет потому, что пока эти потоки выполняются, они держат ссылки на объекты в куче и поэтому их невозможно уничтожить. GC не неуспевает, а просто не делает их сборку.

Answer (score 0):

"Этот StackMemory тоже очищается GC" - неверно. Размер стека постоянен. Заполненая часть меняется, но не с помощью GC, а при процедурных переходах. Другое дело, что GC туда заглядывает, чтобы найти ссылки на живые объекты, которые не надо вычищать.